# Best way to get images out of SQLite DB and show them in WebView (Android)

Tags: android, image, sqlite, webview

I have a SQLite database with several (small) images that I want to be displayed within a WebView. I am trying to use a contentprovider that caches the images to the filesystem, but I think that this is not a good approach.

Is there a possibility to get the imagedate directly to the webview without caching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the images are very small, just have them base64 encoded within the html page you have saved in the SQLite databasse.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<BASE64 IMG STRING>" />
```

The browser should be able to decode them on the fly, and then you do not have to take the "save to filesystem-> read from filesystem" round-trip.

Comment: thanks for that hint, looks like a good idea! what do you mean with "very small" files? i guess that i will need per html page not more than 4-5 images with a total size < 50 KB, average will be perhaps 10KB. do you consider this as a problem?

Comment: Dear daniel, do you have any ideas for bigger pictures? like .jpg ones with size around 1MB or more?